# What is the antonym of 'embedded system?'

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology, antonyms, technical

My resume needs an expression to describe experience I've had working with computers that are not part of a larger hardware system.

I thought of using 'desktops' but this is a very restricted subset of non-embedded systems.

Comment: How about *embedded* and *other* systems? *General purpose*?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Are servers and build machines usually considered general purpose?

Comment: If they aren't, then they would probably be considered *embedded* or *specific use*.

Comment: *General-purpose* is the term [Wikipedia uses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_system).

Comment: independent systems ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Strangely enough, I would consider experience with embedded systems something very specific to mention on a CV - experience with **non-embedded** systems being the default.

If somebody who does not mention experience with embedded systems, I will assume they do not have it, and all experience mentioned refers to non-embedded systems.

That said, if you feel you have to make the distinction, simply calling them non-embedded would do the trick.

It may be my interpretation, but it does feel a bit like looking for a word to describe experience with driving cars *outside* the Formula 1 - I would mention Formula 1 experience if I had it, but otherwise, any driving experience would be assumed not to be Formula 1 anyway.

Comment: I like this answer. Talking about general purpose computing is a bit like mentioning that you can drive a car with an automatic transmission. It's better to talk about the specific aspects of software engineering that you want to emphasize as being in your skill set.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps **stand-alone systems** or **self-contained systems**?

Comment: Not sure this applies. Some embedded systems are more or less self-contained (something like a vending machine or hand-held game), while others are part of larger multi-processor/networked hardware systems.

Answer (score 3):

According to wikipedia,

> An embedded system is a computer system with a dedicated function

Later, the term `general-purpose computer` is used.

Comment: I'd certainly go with "general purpose computer".

Answer (score 0):

The term you are looking for is **Workstation**.

Comment: "Workstations" is another category of computers, distinguished by higher-than-average performance. We want a category including, but not limited to, workstations.